# byte to string error in for loop

Tags: python, unicode, byte

I have variable called out and I stored value there is:

b'0,0.0372549,0.00653595,0,0.00490196,0.00653595,0.897386,0.00653595,0.0294118,0.00653595,0,0,0,0,0,0.00490196,0,0,0,0\n0,0.0158333,0.0179167,0.00277778,0.116111,0.327083,0.0265278,0.174167,0.0623611,0.116806,0.055,0.0270833,0,0,0.01875,0.0333333,0,0,0,0.00625\n0,0.997554,0.00133297,4.75327e-05,0.000118379,6.65359e-05,0.000253487,0.000141784,0.000183293,0.000220498,7.08961e-05,0,0,0,0,0,1.10967e-05,0,0,0\n0,0.082346,0.890084,0,0.000346861,0.0161043,0.0105323,0.000354988,0.00011562,0.00011562,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n0,0.654957,0.306633,0,0.00150356,0.000466853,0.00273321,0.000933707,0.00233427,0.00186741,0,0,0,0,0.0190476,0.00952381,0,0,0,0\n0,0.429955,0.0543849,0.106071,0.0297159,0.0876241,0.16761,0.0435997,0.0293692,0.0167052,0.00492931,0.0143504,0.00664048,0.00127352,0.000520984,0.00405789,5.78871e-05,0,0,0.00313481\n0,0.372212,0.459023,0.00909091,0.0183902,0.00273224,0.0897315,0.00666667,0.0163417,0.000546448,0.000208333,0.00929924,0.00666667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00909091\n0,0.916784,0.0557399,0.00127288,0.0044239,0.00263795,0.00418008,0.00522153,0.00448012,0.0016537,0.0015471,0.00140777,0.00011532,4.21977e-05,4.21977e-05,5.76602e-05,0,0,0,0.000393295\n0,0.817223,0.10791,0.0119181,0.00617358,0.00279979,0.027469,0.00652177,0.00186348,0.00522515,0.0121172,0.000151166,0,0,0,0,0.00017316,0,0,0.000454545\n'

Now I am writing following code:

```
for p in out.rstrip().split('\n'):
    print(p)
```

Now I am getting following error:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

How to solve this error ? I tried unicoding but doesn't work. what would be the for loop code to get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change it to a normal string permanently to remove the b:

```
out = out.decode("utf-8")

for p in out.rstrip().split('\n'):
    print(p)
```

Comment: According to your code b is coming at first, I don't want that.

Comment: he just need to use splitlines() instead of split('\n'), since it is used for str-objects not byte-like objects.

Comment: This should work to get rid of byte b'' at the beginning you must decode the string

Comment: If you don't want to decode the string then split it with `out.rstrip().split(b'\n')`.  That is `b'\n'` instead of `'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use "split" on a 'string', so you basically just need to remove 'b', or even use str(foo) before the loop:

```
foo = '0,0.0372549,0.00653595,0,0.00490196,0.00653595,0.897386,0.00653595,0.0294118,0.00653595,0,0,0,0,0,0.00490196,0,0,0,0\n0,0.0158333,0.0179167,0.00277778,0.116111,0.327083,0.0265278,0.174167,0.0623611,0.116806,0.055,0.0270833,0,0,0.01875,0.0333333,0,0,0,0.00625\n0,0.997554,0.00133297,4.75327e-05,0.000118379,6.65359e-05,0.000253487,0.000141784,0.000183293,0.000220498,7.08961e-05,0,0,0,0,0,1.10967e-05,0,0,0\n0,0.082346,0.890084,0,0.000346861,0.0161043,0.0105323,0.000354988,0.00011562,0.00011562,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n0,0.654957,0.306633,0,0.00150356,0.000466853,0.00273321,0.000933707,0.00233427,0.00186741,0,0,0,0,0.0190476,0.00952381,0,0,0,0\n0,0.429955,0.0543849,0.106071,0.0297159,0.0876241,0.16761,0.0435997,0.0293692,0.0167052,0.00492931,0.0143504,0.00664048,0.00127352,0.000520984,0.00405789,5.78871e-05,0,0,0.00313481\n0,0.372212,0.459023,0.00909091,0.0183902,0.00273224,0.0897315,0.00666667,0.0163417,0.000546448,0.000208333,0.00929924,0.00666667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00909091\n0,0.916784,0.0557399,0.00127288,0.0044239,0.00263795,0.00418008,0.00522153,0.00448012,0.0016537,0.0015471,0.00140777,0.00011532,4.21977e-05,4.21977e-05,5.76602e-05,0,0,0,0.000393295\n0,0.817223,0.10791,0.0119181,0.00617358,0.00279979,0.027469,0.00652177,0.00186348,0.00522515,0.0121172,0.000151166,0,0,0,0,0.00017316,0,0,0.000454545\n'

for p in foo.rstrip().split('\n'):
    print(p)
```

Another solution would be to use 'splitlines' instead, like this:

```
for p in foo.rstrip().splitlines():
    print(p)
```

Comment: You are removing byte statement manually. That is not correct

Comment: Read better what i said :)

Comment: Since you're not giving us complete needs, i'm gonna guess the solutions, and btw the last solution is what you're looking for, it will still be a byte statemnent.

Comment: both are incorrect. I want just the values not b before any string. you written foo by removing the character b from the front.

Comment: Well, i'm gonna call. You're question doesn't say that. Fix it.

Comment: We both answered your question. Please, edit you question if you need anything else from what you asked.